# UICollectionView Always Shows Previous Selection Before Current

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview

I seem to be having a problem I have been trying to solve all day. I have a UICollectionView. Within this view, items from core data are shown(images). You click on the image and it goes to a detail view with more information that was inputted when the image was taken via the camera. The images show fine in the collection view. The problem I am having is that always before showing the current selection, the last selection is shown first. I don't know what to do, here is the code and some output.

```
{
NSInteger selectedFavoriteIndex;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];


//Fetch all the stuff from data store.
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =[[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Favorites"];
self.favorites = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];


}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
return [self.favorites count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCollectionCell *customCell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSManagedObject *favorite = [self.favorites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[customCell.collectionImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[favorite valueForKey:@"image"]]];
return customCell;



}
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
selectedFavoriteIndex = indexPath.item;
NSLog(@"Index path: %@", indexPath);
NSLog(@"Selected Favorite Index: %ld", (long)selectedFavoriteIndex);
NSLog(@"IndexPath.row: %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"IndexPath.item: %ld", (long)indexPath.item);


}  



-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"moment"]) {
    NSManagedObject *selectedFavorite = [self.favorites objectAtIndex:selectedFavoriteIndex];
    ViewMomentViewController *viewMomentViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    viewMomentViewController.favorite = selectedFavorite;
    viewMomentViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;



}


}
```

The formatting kind of got messed up when pasting it here. The format is correct in Xcode though. Here is some output.

Index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

I am also confused as why the path is always subtracting, whether it be 0-0 or 0-2. Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: 0-2 means section 0, item 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `prepareForSegue` gets called before `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. So `prepareForSegue` sees the value of `selectedFavoriteIndex` from the previous call to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

This is really easy to confirm by placing `NSLog` statements in both methods to see the order in which the log message appear in the console.

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1. Rather than using a storyboard-defined segue, do a programatic segue in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` **after** setting `selectedFavoriteIndex` using `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`.
2. Instead of relying on `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to set the selected index, determine the selected index in `prepareForSegue` by calling `[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender]` (when you use a storyboard segue from a collection view cell, the value of `sender` in `prepareForSegue` will be the cell itself, which you can use to determine the index path).

Approach (2) would look something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
NSManagedObject *selectedFavorite = [self.favorites objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The `prepareForSegue` did get called first. So I messed around with both your examples and I am still confused. I changed the `prepareForSegue` to `if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"moment"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedFavorite = [self.favorites objectAtIndex:[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender]];
        ViewMomentViewController *viewMomentViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewMomentViewController.favorite = selectedFavorite;
        viewMomentViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`   and get an error.

Comment: As well as that I messed around with `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and I get no errors, just a blank next view, probably because I am not creating an object to give to that next view. Here's that code `selectedFavoriteIndex = indexPath.item;
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"moment"];`

Comment: This line is wrong: `[self.favorites objectAtIndex:[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender]];` It shouldn't even compile. `objectAtIndex` take an integer but you're trying to give it an `NSIndexPath`. I added more detail in my answer.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much for your help. That last line that you added made it much clearer what I wasn't doing. Now I understand for next time.